# Filter the JSON object where value is not empty or not null on created function on vue.js 3

Tags: api, axios, laravel-8, vuejs3

I want to get the response.data (JSON Object) with value only in the new object on update form i.e. I want to filter it on computed/created on vue 3 - the json object received from API. My backend is Laravel 8 resource API.

On EditPatient.vue - The vue js is

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            patient: {},

        }
    },
    created() {        
      this.$axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
            this.$axios.get(`/api/patients/${this.$route.params.id}`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.patient = response.data // JSON object
                    /* .filter(function(item) {
                    item !== null || item !=='';
                    }) */ // this didn't work. 
                       //I want to response.data and apply to this.patient object. 
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        })
    },
}
```

response.data is

```
{ "created_by": 1, "firstname": "Kamal", "lastname": "", "sex": "M", "address": "Kathmandu, Bagmati, Nepal", "education": "Yes", "grade": "MSc", "alcohol": null, "alcohol_type": null, "weight": "", "kidney_disease": null, "high_bp": "No", "diabetes": null, "heart_attack_stroke": "No",  "present_diabetes": "No",  "systolic": "", "pulse_rate": "" }
```

On laravel api, I got a patient row as follow:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $patient = Patient::find($id);
        return response()->json($patient); // send data in json ojbect for frontend
    }
```

It is better, If I can apply on backend too. Get the columns of single row which has value only.

Comment: @tony19 - Answer should be cleared by the controller if you have been working in larave api. Anyway, if you want real value- then the value of response.data is as below, it will have 150 json values, but it trim to few for your request .
`{ "created_by": 1, "firstname": "Kamal", "lastname": "", "sex": "M", "address": "Kathmandu, Bagmati, Nepal", "education": "Yes", "grade": "MSc", "alcohol": null, "alcohol_type": null, "weight": "", "kidney_disease": null, "high_bp": "No", "diabetes": null, "heart_attack_stroke": "No",  "present_diabetes": "No",  "systolic": "", "pulse_rate": "" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get only the object properties that are not empty/null:

1. Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on the `response.data` object to get an array of key/value pairs.
2. Use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the result, filtering out empty string and `null`.
3. Use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on the filtered result to create an object.

```js
const input = { "created_by": 1, "firstname": "Kamal", "lastname": "", "sex": "M", "address": "Kathmandu, Bagmati, Nepal", "education": "Yes", "grade": "MSc", "alcohol": null, "alcohol_type": null, "weight": "", "kidney_disease": null, "high_bp": "No", "diabetes": null, "heart_attack_stroke": "No",  "present_diabetes": "No",  "systolic": "", "pulse_rate": "" }

const entries = Object.entries(input) // 1️⃣
const nonEmptyOrNull = entries.filter(([key,val]) => val !== '' && val !== null) // 2️⃣
const output = Object.fromEntries(nonEmptyOrNull) // 3️⃣

console.log(output)
```